# rdiff-backup simultaneously

Tags: linux, cron, rdiff-backup

into my backup Linux server (Ubuntu) I have done a system to backup my three servers.
Into etc/crontab I have write line like this:

```
0 0 * * * user rdiff-backup -v9 user@111.111.111.111::/var/www/ /mnt/server1/www
0 1 * * * user rdiff-backup -v9 user@222.222.222.222::/var/www/ /mnt/server2/www
0 2 * * * user rdiff-backup -v9 user@333.333.333.333::/var/www/ /mnt/server3/www
```

But if the first rdiff-backup don't finish before 2:00 am, and the second rdiff-backup start is a problem? Can two or more rdiff-backup run together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, rdiff-backup works in parallel. Especially in your case, since the hosts and directories are separate, it shouldn't cause a problem. But if you encounter any performance issues due to multiple rdiff-backup scripts running in parallel, then you might need to modify your cron so that a script starts only after the one immediately preceding it finishes. In `bash` you usually use the `&&` to concatenate the processes, as in `script1 && script2 && script2`. If the first script finishes successfully, the second one starts..and so on.

Comment: nice.. I don't know how to make a script but is interesting to do for the performance and to debug if some backup doesn't work!